# Memory for python.exe on Windows 7 python 32 - Numpy uses half of the available memory only?

Tags: python, arrays, memory, numpy

I'm loading large h5 files into memory using `numpy` `ndarray`'s. I read that my system (Win 7 prof., 6 GB RAM) is supposed to allow python.exe to use about 2 GB of physical memory.

However I'm getting a `MemoryError` already just shy of 1 GB. Even stranger this lower limit seems to only apply for `numpy array`'s but not for a `list`.

I've tested my memory consumption using the following function found [here](http://fa.bianp.net/blog/2013/different-ways-to-get-memory-consumption-or-lessons-learned-from-memory_profiler/):

```
import psutil
import gc
import os
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import pause

def memory_usage_psutil():
    # return the memory usage in MB
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    mem = process.get_memory_info()[0]/float(2**20)
    return mem
```

**Test 1:** Testing memory limits for an ordinary list

```
print 'Memory - %d MB' %memory_usage_psutil() # prints memory usage after imports
a = []
while 1:
    try:
        a.append([x*2000 for x in xrange(10000)])
    except MemoryError:
        print 'Memory - %d MB' %memory_usage_psutil()
        a = []
        print 'Memory - %d MB' %memory_usage_psutil()
        print 'run garbage collector: collected %d objects.' %gc.collect()
        print 'Memory - %d MB\n\n' %memory_usage_psutil()
        break
```

Test 1 prints:

```
Memory - 39 MB
Memory - 1947 MB
Memory - 1516 MB
run garbage collector: collected 0 objects.
Memory - 49 MB
```

**Test 2:** Creating a number of large `np.array`'s

```
shape = (5500,5500)
names = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'h']

try:
    for n in names:
        globals()[n] = np.ones(shape, dtype='float64')
        print 'created variable %s with %0.2f MB'\
        %(n,(globals()[n].nbytes/2.**20))
except MemoryError:
    print 'MemoryError, Memory - %d MB. Deleting files..'\
    %memory_usage_psutil()
    pause(2)
    # Just added the pause here to be able to observe
    # the spike of memory in the Windows task manager.
    for n in names:
        globals()[n] = []
    print 'Memory - %d MB' %memory_usage_psutil()
    print 'run garbage collector: collected %d objects.' %gc.collect()
    print 'Memory - %d MB' %memory_usage_psutil()
```

Test 2 prints:

```
Memory - 39 MB
created variable b with 230.79 MB
created variable c with 230.79 MB
created variable d with 230.79 MB
created variable g with 230.79 MB
MemoryError, Memory - 964 MB. Deleting files..
Memory - 39 MB
run garbage collector: collected 0 objects.
Memory - 39 MB
```

My question: Why do I get a `MemoryError` before I'm even close to the 2GB limit and why is there a difference in memory limits for a `list` and `np.array` respectively or what am I missing?
I'm using python 2.7 and numpy 1.7.1

Comment: I guess I could work around this by appending all arrays into a list, however I would have to change my code accessing the arrays and it would certainly not be a nice solution.

Comment: It's time for you to go 64-bit. Use http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs or 64-bit cygwin.

Comment: Yip, eventually I gave up and am now on 64 bit. Should have done that in the first place; it would have saves me so much hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably happening because numpy array is using some C array library (for speed), that is somewhere calling a malloc. This then fails because it cannot allocate a *contiguous* 1GB of memory. I am further guessing that Python lists are implemented as a linked list, thus the memory needed for a list need not be contiguous. Hence, if you have enough memory available but it is fragmented, your array malloc would fail but your linked list would allow you to use all of the noncontiguous pieces.

Comment: Python list is an array (not linked list), the problem, I guess, is because the multidimensional list in python aren't contiguous because the parent list contains just pointers to the child list, while numpy multidimensional array are actually just one big array so they have to be contiguous.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanations. I changed my test 2 to load a larger number of smaller arrays (~60 MB/array) and I only get a MemoryError at around 1.5 GB. This behavior indicates that more numpy arrays are able to find contiguous space in the memory. When I further reduce the array size to about 10 MB then I'm able to utilize 1817 MB of memory.